# Empty list of managed Foursquare venues

Tags: foursquare

We have an issue with retrieval of **managed venues** via Foursquare API.

I can't see that my home location in my managed locations list.

We use this api call :
"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/**venues/managed**?oauth_token=' + token", 
but it always returns an empty list.

Could a home location be retrieved using this api call, or there is a special api method?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your home venue is not a managed venue. Managed venues refer specifically to businesses that have been claimed by their owners, and the venues/managed endpoint returns venues that have been claimed in such a fashion. It is not possible to use the API to determine a user's home.