# How to get simulated API response for foursquare managed venues during development

Tags: foursquare

I am trying to make use of the [managed venues API](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/managed) on Foursquare. As I am managing no venues a call to `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/managed` always returns an empty list of venues.

[Other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785680/empty-list-of-managed-foursquare-venues) suggest  there is a `/simulate/venues/managed` endpoint (which is not documented in the API docs). This endpoint seems to exist, but also returns an empty list.

Is there another way to develop a tool using the `managed venues` endpoint or do I have to register a managed venue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send an email to api@foursquare.com, with your userid and OAuth client ID. We can set you up with a test venue that you manage to test out these endpoints.